# Is it OK to add external Members to Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have built a website (.NET 6 / MVC) that is used to manage the licencing of another (SaaS) product.

We log in as Administrators, and users from other companies log in to order, pay, manage their subscriptions etc.

These users are added as Members to a dedicated Azure Active Directory.

A concern has been raised that this is not a great idea – AAD is designed to hold users from a single company, and whilst Guest access is permitted, this is something different, since we are adding these external users as Members.

One concern is that external users might be able to see each other if they know where to look. By default, [Members can see each other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#member-and-guest-users):

> Member users can register applications, manage their own profile photo and mobile phone number, change their own password, and invite B2B guests. These users can also read all directory information (with a few exceptions).”

Whilst it is possible to lock down access to the Azure Portal, and Graph, and PowerShell, MS states that these measures are [not security measures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#restrict-member-users-default-permissions).

So, the question is, have we made a mistake? I am not asking for alternative solutions, I’m simply trying to figure out if what we have is “bad”, and whether we can/should continue to use AAD in this way, as long as we add appropriate restrictions.

Comment: Have you considered setting their userType to Guest? This can be done through PowerShell for example. That would limit their rights within the tenant.

Comment: Interesting @juunas, I had not considered this. I was under the impression Guests had to exist in their own AAD, but it seems not https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/user-properties

Comment: Being an external or local user and having userType Member or Guest are two different things :)

Answer (score 0):

> **Yes**, it is okay to add external Members to Azure Active Directory, one has to configure few restrictions to ensure security.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

To secure the external users access, you can configure **MFA**:

*Under Assignments -> Select Guest or external users -> and select based on your requirement.*

[image]

You can also create Conditional Policy to allow **external users to access Apps** like below:

[image]

This will not allow external users to access all the applications under the Tenant.

You can also manage the **[lifecycle of the External Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-external-users#manage-the-lifecycle-of-external-users)** like below:

[image]

> So, the question is, have we made a mistake? I’m simply trying to figure out if what we have is “bad”, and whether we can/should continue to use AAD in this way, as long as we add appropriate restrictions.

**Hence**, managing users from other organizations as members using AAD is not necessarily a bad practice. It depends on how your AAD environment is set up and protected.

- You can continue to utilize AAD to manage people from various organizations as members if you have put in place the proper security measures. To keep your AAD environment secure and compliant, it's crucial to frequently examine and update your security settings.

For more in detail, please **refer** below GitHub blogs:

[azure-docs/3-secure-access-plan.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/fundamentals/3-secure-access-plan.md) by v-edmckillop

[azure-docs/entitlement-management-external-users.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-external-users.md) by John Flores